Which phrase is being modified in the given sentence?
What is the phrase 'payable in foreign currency' modifying in the following sentence?:

The borrowing cost ceiling includes spread over relevant benchmark rate, loan related
insurance premium and other loan related fees payable in foreign currency, except
commitment fee, cost & expenses and fees payable in local currency.

Does it modify only 'other loan related fees' or it also modify 'loan related insurance premium and spread over relevant benchmark rate?

The lack of a comma before "and other loan related fees" suggests to me that it applies to the entire list.

Probably if you know what all those things are, you can work out which  are payable in foreign currency and which aren't, and it'll make more sense. Otherwise, speak to a lawyer or financial advisor because we can't help you.

At least as a question it is not too simple a one. I would think it modifies all monies that are previously enumerated. As you say, there is no comma for it.

The sentence is so poorly constructed that it's impossible to tell.

I've tried and failed; I'm sure BillJ is right. Despite the use of both '&' and 'and' in an attempt to clarify, this sentence is poorly constructed.
